# Is it possible to run Quarkus in native mode with reactive SQL client connecting to Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: netty, google-cloud-sql, quarkus, graalvm-native-image

Is it possible to run Quarkus in native mode with reactive SQL client connecting to Google Cloud SQL? [This guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-google-cloud#using-cloud-sql-with-a-reactive-sql-client) says that would require Netty native transport which according to [this issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/10616) doesn't work in native mode. Is there some other option maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing "native" mode between ["Native Netty transports"](https://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html) and ["Graalvm Native Image"](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/) which are two different concepts.

The Cloud SQL Java connector also has a reactive socketfactory for r2dbc-postgres: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/r2dbc-postgres.md